# Android RecyclerView Multiple Filters with Firebase Realtime DataBase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, filter, android-recyclerview

I'm using Realtime DataBase in Firebase, and I want to make multiple filters on it, for example, I want to get all students that their age between 10 and 15 and their marks are equal 90 and their genders are male and more than...

Is there any way to implement that logic in my app?

## Edit

I could achieve that by using this method.

```
public List<Tasks> multipleFilter(String PriorityFilter, String startDateFilter, String endDateFilter, List<Tasks> listAllTasks) {
    List<Tasks> listTasksAfterFiltering = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Tasks task_obj : listAllTasks) {
        String PriorityTask = task_obj.getPriority();
        String startDateTask = task_obj.getStartDate();
        String endDateTask = task_obj.getEndDate();
        if (PriorityFilter.equals(PriorityTask) || PriorityFilter.isEmpty())
            if (startDateFilter.equals(startDateTask) || startDateFilter.isEmpty())
                if (endDateFilter.equals(endDateTask) || endDateFilter.isEmpty())
                    if (!PriorityFilter.isEmpty() || !startDateFilter.isEmpty() || !endDateFilter.isEmpty()) {
                        listTasksAfterFiltering.add(task_obj);
                    }
    }

    return listTasksAfterFiltering;

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: All of first, I checked from documents in Realtime Database and I founded the Query but it is not enough for my task, and I tried nested  IF as an instead solution but it's so difficult and very complex code.

do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to your question.